# Black screen on startup

Tags: mac

I have 2 mac pro desktop systems: 5,1 running Sierra and a mac pro 1,1 running SUSE Linux. I remove the SUSE disk from the 1,1 and insert a working, bootable disk with Lion on it in its place. All I get is chime, black screen with cursor and an unseen keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

You should not insert a "working, bootable disk with...."
You should ***install*** Lion on the Mac Pro.